# How to auto detect trim and crop part of image using OpenCV python?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I am working on image to text convert program where I want to remove surrounding unnecessary images, background and text so that it emphasizes on the main  area where I want the text to be extracted from!

See the warning label from the medicine box. How do I get to extract only the intended area of the image!? Because all the other elements cause noise and effect the accuracy of the extraction.

Comment: If your region of interest is always yellow, and the rest of the usually is not the same color, you can get help from some color detection technique, like the one described here: https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d97/tutorial_threshold_inRange.html

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is to find the find the **contour** with the **maximum number of child contours**.
The contour with the maximum number of children is the one with maximum letters inside it.

This is only the first stage for coarse filtering, and there are more stages:

- Convert to Grayscale, and convert to binary image.
- Find contours and hierarchy.
  Use `RETR_TREE` for creating a tree of contours within contours.
- Find parent contour with the maximum number of child contours.
- Crop the bounding rectangle of the above contour from the image.
- Find connected components (clusters).
- Delete large, small, tall and wide clusters - not letters for sure.
- Use "closing" morphological operation for uniting text area.
- Find contours, and crop the bounding rectangle of contour with maximum area.

The problem is challenging, and my answer may be over-fitted for the image you posted.
You may refine the heuristics for getting more general solution.

---

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Read input image
img = cv2.imread('dizziness.jpg')

# Convert to Grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Convert to binary image - use THRESH_OTSU for automatic threshold.
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# Find contours and hierarchy, use RETR_TREE for creating a tree of contours within contours
cnts, hiers = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[-2:]  # [-2:] indexing takes return value before last (due to OpenCV compatibility issues).

# https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html
# Hierarchy Representation in OpenCV
# So each contour has its own information regarding what hierarchy it is, who is its child, who is its parent etc. 
# OpenCV represents it as an array of four values : [Next, Previous, First_Child, Parent]
parent = hiers[0, :, 3]

# Find parent contour with the maximum number of child contours
# Use np.bincount for counting the number of instances of each parent value.
# https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html#numpy.bincount
hist = np.bincount(np.maximum(parent, 0))
max_n_childs_idx = hist.argmax()

# Get the contour with the maximum child contours
c = cnts[max_n_childs_idx]

# Get bounding rectangle
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)

# Crop the bounding rectangle out of img
img = img[y:y+h, x:x+w, :]
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Convert to binary image (after cropping) and invert polarity
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

#cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh);cv2.waitKey(0);cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# Find connected components (clusters)
nlabel,labels,stats,centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(thresh, connectivity=8)

# Delete large, small, tall and wide clusters - not letters for sure
max_area = 2000
min_area = 10
max_width = 100
max_height = 100
for i in range(1, nlabel):
    if (stats[i, cv2.CC_STAT_AREA] > max_area) or \
       (stats[i, cv2.CC_STAT_AREA] < min_area) or \
       (stats[i, cv2.CC_STAT_WIDTH] > max_width) or \
       (stats[i, cv2.CC_STAT_HEIGHT] > max_height):
        thresh[labels == i] = 0

#cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh);cv2.waitKey(0);cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# Use "closing" morphological operation for uniting text area
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, np.ones((50, 50)))

# Find contours once more
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[-2]

# Get contour with maximum area
c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)

# Get bounding rectangle
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)

# Crop the bounding rectangle out of img (leave some margins)
out = img[y-5:y+h+5, x-5:x+w+5]

# Show output
cv2.imshow('out', out);
cv2.waitKey(0);
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That code works and helps me understand the logic needed, but if I use it for some other image, it doesn't work that accurately. Still need a general solution. I'll work on that. Thank you so much though you have been very helpful.