# Get dimensions of composition, minus whitespace

Tags: imagick

I have a series of images (10000's) that are all *object-on-white-bg* composition. Images are let's say 1000x1000 and objects within are any size. I want to get the actual dimensions of the object, which could be something like 400x500 or 350x520. The rest of the image is just whitespace (but there is some dirtyness to the whitespace e.g. 2% off-white)

I just need analysis of the images; I don't need to export or save data.

**QUESTION:** Using `imagemagick`, What's the most *performant* way to get actual object dimensions on a clean background? I just wonder is there a better `imagemagick` tool to use than [trimImage()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.trimimage.php).

Here is one working method, roughly:
(PHP/Laravel project)

```
$path = 'images/myTestImage.jpg';
$imagick = new \Imagick(realpath($path));
$originalDimensions = $imagick->getImageWidth()."x".$imagick->getImageHeight();

// Using imagemagick trimImage(), with fuzz value to take care of dirty white pixels.
$imagick->trimImage(5000);

$newDimensions = $imagick->getImageWidth()."x".$imagick->getImageHeight();
```

Example image:
[image]

Comment: You appear to be using PHP **Imagick** rather than **ImageMagick** so maybe you could edit your tags? Unfortunately PHP isn't very good at threading or multiprocessing so I don't think you are going to get anything very performant in these days of fatter CPUs (more cores) rather than taller CPUs (more GHz). Are you stuck with PHP?

Comment: Thx, edited tags. Yea stuck with PHP. This is for a legacy codebase. There's already other logic implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ideas. I don't know enough about your environment or images to say which, if any, will work best or be appropriate for you.

---

You may be able to use the JPEG *"shrink-on-load"* feature to reduce the demand on I/O, memory and CPU cycles while loading your images - especially if the edges of your shapes are fuzzy by a couple of percent, the reduced size will not make much difference to the finding of the shape outlines. I'll demonstrate by creating a test image to trim:

```
convert -size 2000x2000 xc:black -fill white -draw "rectangle 100,100 200,200" image.jpg
```

Now get trim box:

```
time convert image.jpg -format %@ image.jpg info:
112x112+96+96112x112+96+96
real    0m0.128s
user    0m0.803s
sys     0m0.097s
```

Now do same thing again but with *"shrink-on-load"* to 1/4 the width and height:

```
time convert -define jpeg:size=500x500 image.jpg -format %@ image.jpg info:
28x28+24+2428x28+24+24
real    0m0.040s
user    0m0.054s
sys     0m0.014s
```

Note that is 3-4x faster, also that the features (including trim box) are correspondingly reduced.

---

You may be able to use [vips](https://github.com/libvips/php-vips), though you would have to add the corresponding tag to get John's (the author) input. If `vips` can do this, it may be an excellent option. I think you would need to use `find_trim()` which is documented [here](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/libvips-arithmetic.html#vips-find-trim).

---

You may able to *"shell out"* using `system()` to get a tool such as **GNU Parallel** to use multiple CPU cores to process your images in parallel. It's a quick, easy install. You can just try the following in your Terminal without PHP to get an idea how fast it is:

```
parallel --bar 'magick -format "%f:%@\n" {} info:' ::: *.jpg
```

If you have too many images for your command line, you can pump the names into it this way:

```
find . -name \*.jpg -print0 | parallel -0 --bar 'magick -format "%f:%@\n" {} info:'
```

---

You could write some Python that takes a load of filenames to check with **OpenCV** which will be really fast, and then get **GNU Parallel** to call that Python with as many filenames as your shell can handle (`-X` option) to amortise the overhead of starting the Python interpreter over as many images as possible. I mean this:

```
parallel -X script.py ::: *.jpg
```

Then your Python would be of the form:

```
for f in sys.argv[1:]:
    image = cv2.imread(... probably greyscale)
    cv2.findContours ... à la Rotem https://stackoverflow.com/a/60833042/2836621
```

Or, rather than `findContours()` you can probably do it faster as suggested by Divakar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64048779/2836621).